# check if value Y in column Z in table X

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I want to write a function to check if Table X has a row with Value Y in column Z. If this condition is satisfied return True, otherwise return False.

I write the following function:

```
def valueInDatabase(cursor,value,table, col):
    check = cursor.execute("""SELECT %s from %s"""%(col,table))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    if value in result:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

and I test my function with the following code:

```
conn = sqlite.connect(":memory:")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE problem1 (x int unique)""")
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO problem1(x) VALUES (?)",[(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,)])
print valueInDatabase(cursor,5,'problem1','x')
print valueInDatabase(cursor,2,'problem1','x')
```

it prints "false" and "false", but it should print "true" and "false". Anyone can help me to fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `print result` and it reveals that result is full of tuples. So I updated your `if` statement accordingly.

```
def valueInDatabase(cursor,value,table, col):
    check = cursor.execute("""SELECT %s from %s"""%(col,table))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print result           # returns [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
    # So we should check for the tuple, value, like this:
    if (value,) in result:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a row has a value in certain column, your check should be something like:

```
if value in row[col]:
```

Also, you do a `result = cursor.fetchall()` which returns a iterator of rows of results. I believe you should do your check in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use SQL feature instead of fetching all record from table.

```
def valueInDatabase(cursor,value,table, col):
    check = cursor.execute(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) from {} WHERE {} = ?".format(col, table), 
        [value])
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row[0] > 0
```

`?` should be replaced with correct placeholder marker according to DB-API module you're using.

**SIDE NOTE**

As shown in the above example:

```
if condition:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

can be replaced with:

```
return condition
```